# Using oop in php confusion

Tags: php, oop

Hey guys am new to php app development ..and i have learned about oop..The code which i have seen.

```
class Dictionary {
    // ...
private $dictio;

    function asArray() {
        return $this->translations;
    }

    function getType() {
        return $this->type;
    }

    function export() {
        $this->dictio->export( $this );
    }

    function import() {
        $this->dictio->import( $this );
    }
}
```

I know function `asArray` and `getType` is fine ..but when i called `export` `import` i get error like `undefined call to non member function`..is it possible to call like `$this->dictio->export()` in php ??

Hope you guys can help me ..Thanks

Comment: show the code which calls the error and the exact error message, with line number please

Comment: $dictio is not an object

Comment: @davidxd333 i just need to know we can use any other function instead of import ..like $this->varname->funcname() ..if we can do like this please demostrate it in answer

Comment: @user3852154 You can't chain a method onto `$dictio` without assigning that variable to an object. I don't understand what you're trying to do with those functions so I cannot provide a valid answer or example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a member attribute named dictio. That is why PHP throws that error.
You need to initiate an attribute that implements export and import.

Comment: CAN YOU edit the qus to use like that $this->somevar->somefunc()

Comment: What are you trying to do with export and import ?

Comment: i just need to know if we can use any other function instead of import ..like $this->varname->funcname() ..if we can do like this please demostrate it in answer –

Comment: It only works if you have a construct method  like this " public function __construct()
{ $this->dictio = new Dictio(); // or something else }  And the class that the dictio variable is implementing needs to have the export and import method because $this->dictio->export means run the method export that is in the dictio variable or class. I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a class variable `$dictio` which is an instance of a class that implements methods `export()` and `import()`.

In your case, `$dictio` is an empty variable, so it will throw an error if you try to call the method `export()` from it.

Comment: this belongs in a comment

Comment: Well, it answers the question.

Comment: Note the "which is an instance of a class that implements methods export() and import()."

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel CAN YOU edit the qus to use like that  $this->somevar->somefunc()